# Library of opencl not found?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to compile an opencl sample code but I am getting the following error

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -loclUtil_x86_64
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lshrutil_x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../..//OpenCL//bin//linux/release/DeviceQuery] Error 1
```

I am using intel based machine ...
My make file is 
`EXECUTABLE := DeviceQuery
CCFILES     := devQury.cpp
include ../common/common_opencl.mk`

Any help would be of great help

Thanks ,
Piyush

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the OpenCL library **(libOpenCL.so)** is present in /usr/lib. This should have been put in place by the driver, so you shouldn't have to do anything.

If not then copy **libOpenCL.so** present in your cuda toolkit (lib64) to the above location.

```
sudo cp /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so /usr/lib
```

This fixes the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the OpenCL SDK from either Intel or AMD?  If not then perhaps you should follow [these instructions](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-06-24/install-opencl-on-debianubuntu-orderly/).  If you have an SDK installed then your makefile is probably missing -L... in the compiler command line, where ... is the path to the lib folder in the OpenCL SDK that should contain a file libOpenCL.a or something similar.